# How to throw Exception from a method and prevent multiple threading

Tags: c#, .net-core, single-threaded

I have a question which I need pointers to how best to solve it.

So I have a Booking Class  with 2 methods:

1. StartBooking();
2. GetBookingStatus.

These are the conditions to execute this function:

When a StartBooking() function is called and another thread or the same thread
Calls the function again, it should throw `BookingInProgressException`.
When GetBookingStatus() is called by another thread when it is in progress
Should throw a ReadinProgressException.
Calling GetBookingStatus() without calling StartBooking() should throw a NoStartBookingException.

Any pointers will be really helpful.

Comment: What about mutex or lock? https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1d42da/thread-locking-in-C-Sharp/ Usually there is scenario of blocking of execution of certain code until previous caller is finished and second thread is stopped on locker object.  Another tool is SingleThreadApartment: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/890/how-to-solve-csharp-exception-current-thread-must-be-set-to-single-thread-apartment-sta-mode-before-ole-calls-can-be-made-ensure-that-your-main-function-has-stathreadattribute-marked-on-it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.